# Triple Boot Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, multi-boot, bootloader

The toshiba laptop has Win 7 Home Edition. I resized the partition (shrink). I made two other partitions to install two Win XP SP3. Trying to have 1x Win7, 2x WinXP, when resized the partition, i made sure Win 7 is still working. Then i installed one WinXP. then the other. Now at the boot Menu I only see two Win XP, my Windows 7 disappeared. But when I boot into Win XP i can still see C: with the Win 7 on it. It just wont show up in the boot menu.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3):

Yeap. You've made a mistake. You should not install older system along side the newer. The older one did not recognize boot setings of Win7 and it made overwrite. This should be done the other way around. First the older ones then the newer one.

How to fix it? Simple enough - put the Windows 7 installation disk in the CD-ROM and start from the CD. Choose option recovery and fix boot process / MBR. The Win7 Installation disk recovery tool should recognize all three systems and add them to system boot records.

Comment: I will try this and let you know what happens.